# Не видит библиотеку при сборке приложения под android Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, graphviz

В общем, пишу небольшое приложение на С++ в Qt, которое сможет отрисовывать графы, использую стороннюю библиотеку Graphviz в Qt. При дебаге приложения для пк все работает отлично, но при сборке приложения под android отказывается видеть библиотеку. [image: Не видит библиотеку]
Пишу под android с qt первый раз, прошу подсказать может чего забыл сделать...

Comment: а вы что-то сделали, чтобы библиотеку видно было?

Comment: Ничего не делал, так как при разработке для ПК ничего не требовалось.

Comment: это странно, обычно в проекте в переменных INCLUDEPATH и LIBS надо, что-то указывать. Потом graphviz же для андроида нет на сайте, надо наверное собирать из исходников?

Comment: Прошу прощения не вспомнил сразу. В cpp файле указывал LIBS += -lgvs -lcgraph -lcdt

Comment: Система у вас  какая? Ubuntu? Как библиотека устанавливалась?

Comment: Система Ubuntu. Через консоль, (sudo apt install graphviz-lib и sudo apt install libgraphviz-dev)

Comment: ну тогда всё понятно, вы установили скомпилированную библиотеку для ubuntu, а для андроида надо или собирать самостоятельно из исходников или попытаться найти, может кто-то уже собрал